# On installing Java for both 32bit and 64bit

Tags: java, path, installation

How do you think set the `PATH` in **Windows 7 64bit** to have access to both 32 and 64 bit compilers. I have noteiced that appart from different folders everything such as `java.exe`, `javac.exe`, etc. are exactly the same. I believe the first path in the `PATH` variable (either with 32bit binaries or the 64bit) will take precedence.

My idea would be to change 64bit compiler's name (java.exe) and class execute program's name (javac.exe) and le't say add `64bit` postfix but I am not sure if that would work. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

java is not the compiler, that's javac. Also, the compiler generates the same byte-code on 64-bit as it does on 32-bit. Assuming you are using pure Java, the only distinction is in the run-time (or JRE) where a 64-bit JRE can address more memory. If you have native code then you must match the settings those libraries were compiled with . But, in general, if you are on a 64-bit system with more then 4 gigabytes of memory, only a 64-bit JRE can use the extra memory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant javac as a compiler. Thanks for the advice. I've got more than 4GB and it's 64bit system so I'll stick to 64bit then. Cheers!